# R show data from matrix/ dataframe but not the column or row names

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, r-colnames

I have a matrix in r (or dataframe) and would like to display the data but without the column names.

This because the data contained will be part of a markdown to word and therefore only data that I have within the table is relevant.

The final objective is to bring data contained that was generated with an r-script into a markdown document.

Table example:

```
df<-matrix(c("Name: John Doe", "Country: USA", "State: IL","Role: Consultant","Company: Microsoft","University: NYU"),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

Any ideas on how to display the data but not the column/row titles

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the end-goal is, but if you just want to save it without column names you can just do `write.table(df, "path", col.names = F, ...)`

Comment: Thank you, not quite, as I want to use this into Markdown rather than just extracting into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cat`:

```
cat(df, sep = "\n")
```

Output:

```
Name: John Doe
State: IL
Company: Microsoft
Country: USA
Role: Consultant
University: NYU
```